# GeoServer Style referencing SQL Server data store

Tags: geoserver, sql, sld, server

I have a SQL server (2012) based data store in GeoServer (version 2.6) .
For better readability I created a spatial layer with a whitespace in a column (attribute) name. 
[image]

Trying to use a style with the attribute "landslide code" reasults in an error.

```
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: The requested Style can not be used with this layer.  The style specifies an attribute of landslide code and the layer is some layername
```

The problem seems to be the whitespace in the attribute name.
I tried to use the xml coding for whitespace , no success.
I also tried to encapsulate the attribute name in square brackets [], which is the standard for sql server. Also no success.

How can I use attribute names with whitespaces in their names?
SQL server allows this!

Comment: can you add the part of the sld that uses the property?

Comment: <ogc:Filter>

      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

        <ogc:PropertyName>landslide_ code</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </ogc:Filter>

Comment: try with out _ <ogc:PropertyName>landslide code</ogc:PropertyName>

Comment: sorry, was a typo, without the underscore i get the same problem

Comment: can you turn logging upto debug and look for the query

Comment: ok, I did, where exactly can I find what GS is sending to the database though?

Comment: search the log file for "select"

Comment: There are no select statements sent.   at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.checkStyle(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:1145)
 at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:402)
 at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:83)
 at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1430)
 at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:628)

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask - can you remove the whitespace from the field name? I imagine you will encounter more problems like this in different applications over time and this bucks a generally accepted convention on field names that will confuse other developers in future.

Comment: Yes, sure, I can remove the white space. And I know that it is not good practice to have them in field names in the first place. In fact, it's the very first thing I tell my colleagues not to do :-). The original table in fact has not spaces. I just created a view in the database and renamed a field. I was thinking it could be a way to have more desciptive column names, which later in a query tool just spek for themselves. Actually, the layer displays perfectly nice when I don't use the field in the SLD.

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer is based on GeoTools and GeoTools is following the definition of "XML element name", so **whitespaces are not allowed**.

See the source: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/284bb1273e47b02d6d5fca248732e2ab564e818e/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/expression/SimpleFeaturePropertyAccessorFactory.java#L83-L88